# Run a line in MainActivity After a thread finishes its job or returns a value in android

Tags: java, android

I am trying to run a line of code after my thread finishes its task in the MainActivity but that line runs even before the thread completes its task.

```
new PostUsernameAndPassword(username,password, UserAuthenticationFailAlert);

//this line is running before the value is set in the thread!!
if(UserAuthenticationFailAlert.getText().toString().equals("Access granted")){
//do something
}
```

How do I do something like function.then() in android?

Answer (score 0):

You can use callbacks. Pass a callback function to your `PostUsernameAndPassword` as a param, and then call it AFTER the job is done.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/asynchronous-synchronous-callbacks-java/

Answer (score 0):

Define `job` as `private var job = Job()` in your class.

```
job = Job()
        GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO + job) {
           new PostUsernameAndPassword(username,password, UserAuthenticationFailAlert);
            withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                if(UserAuthenticationFailAlert.getText().toString().equals("Access granted")){

}     
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

As after Java 8 you can make asynchronous call using CompletableFuture supplyAsync method.

```
CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(()->new PostUsernameAndPassword(username,password, UserAuthenticationFailAlert))
.thenApply(out->if(UserAuthenticationFailAlert.getText().toString().equals("Access granted")){
//do something
}  );
```

More reference can be found in-->
1.https://www.baeldung.com/java-completablefuture
2. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ImtZgX1nmr8